# How does the C# RSACryptoServiceProvider Encrypt() method work?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am curious since RSA is not a block cipher, yet the Encrypt() method can take an arbitrary amount of data to encrypt.

Does it use AES+RSA hybrid encryption? Or does it simply use RSA (incorrectly) as a block cipher?

Comment: Where does it say the Encrypt method can take an arbitrary amount of data? Certainly not in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

> yet the Encrypt() method can take an arbitrary amount of data to encrypt

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.encrypt.aspx) it can't

> Maximum Length of rgb Parameter
>   Modulus size -2 -2*hLen, where hLen is the size of the hash.

It even has a `CryptographicException` that reads "The length of the rgb parameter is greater than the maximum allowed length.".

Comment: When checking "(rsa.KeySize / 8) - (sha1computedHashSize * 2 + 2)" I get 1024/8 - (20*2 + 2) ie 86 (that's with OAEP padding).

Answer (score 1):

> Does it use AES+RSA hybrid encryption?

**No** it does not. If this is what you're looking for then you have to do it yourself or check my old [blog](http://pages.infinit.net/ctech/20031101-0151.html) entry on the subject.

> Or does it simply use RSA (incorrectly) as a block cipher?

**No** it does not. It will apply a padding (either PKCS#1 1.5 or OAEP) to the supplied `byte[]` and encrypt it. As such is **does** have length limitations (as others already pointed out).

Here's how it looks like (from Mono's BCL source code).

```
public byte[] Encrypt (byte[] rgb, bool fOAEP) 
{
    // choose between OAEP or PKCS#1 v.1.5 padding
    AsymmetricKeyExchangeFormatter fmt = null;
    if (fOAEP)
        fmt = new RSAOAEPKeyExchangeFormatter (rsa);
    else
        fmt = new RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeFormatter (rsa);

    return fmt.CreateKeyExchange (rgb);
}
```